# UILabel which changes height for it's content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm programming an `UILabel` which should change it's size depending on it's content. Here my code:

```
- (NSDictionary *)labelAttributesForText:(NSString *)text andWidth:        (CGFloat)width
{
    CGSize constrain = CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX);

    UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"     size:17];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              labelFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                              paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                              nil];

    CGRect labelRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constrain
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attrDict
                                          context:nil];
    CGSize labelSize = labelRect.size;

    int numberOfLines = (CGFloat)labelSize.height / labelFont.lineHeight;

    NSLog(@"%s:%f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,labelSize.height);
    NSLog(@"%s:%f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,labelFont.lineHeight);
    NSLog(@"%s:%d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,numberOfLines);

    NSDictionary *labelFormatings = @{@"labelHeight":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",labelSize.height],
                                      @"numberOfLines":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberOfLines]};
    return labelFormatings;
}
```

The method gets called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The Problem is, that it's calculating a wrong height, that means when I call the method for a given text and set it's parent `UILabel` to the calculated height the text doesn't fit the UILabel. And additionally there is a problem with the `numberOfLines` variable which is calculated with a wrong value of `labelFont.lineHeight` which you can see in the `NSLog` statements. So my question is what can I do to get the right height and why is `labelFont.lineHeight` equal 0?

**EDIT**

Here my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault         reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.     Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla     pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui         officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    cell.textLabel.text = text;

    //_labelHeight = [self computeHeightWithText:text font:cell.textLabel.font width:cell.frame.size.width];
    _labelHeight = [self labelHeightForText:text andWidth:cell.frame.size.width];
    NSLog(@"%slabel Height:%f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,_labelHeight);
    NSLog(@"%s:%@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,cell.textLabel.font);

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = _labelHeight / cell.textLabel.font.lineHeight;


    return cell;
}
```

Suddenly I've made a few changes, the method is now called labelHeightForText:andWidth:.

Comment: `-sizeToFit` is not an option?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you are trying to do so this might not be helpful but if you don't have any special need to actually calculate the size of the label you can just set the numberOfLines property to 0. This will make the label have dynamic number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForFont:(NSString *)fontName andString:(NSString *)str andSize:(float)fontSize andLabelWidth:(float)lblWidth
    {
        NSString *text = str;
        CGFloat width = lblWidth;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
        NSAttributedString *attributedText =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc]
         initWithString:text
         attributes:@
         {
         NSFontAttributeName: font
         }];
        CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   context:nil];
        CGSize size = rect.size;
        return size.height;

    }
```

and Use this call about method and get height for label and then update frame

```
 CGFloat lbl_height = [self getLabelHeightForFont:@"System- System" andString:@"your string or message" andSize:15 andLabelWidth: yourLabel.frame.size.width]
        lbl_address.numberOfLines = 0;
        lbl_address.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [lbl_address setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lbl_address.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_address.frame.origin.x, lbl_address.frame.origin.y, lbl_address.frame.size.width, lbl_height+5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know, if this helps

```
NSString *yourText = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // your text

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,
                                [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil]; // set custom attributes

    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourText attributes:attributes];

    CGRect paragraphRect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(625, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                 context:nil]; //here 625 is width of label

    NSLog(@"height = %f", paragraphRect.size.height);
```

Comment: Hey with your solution I get the same exact height like I get with my solution... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for manual calculating the height:

```
- (CGFloat)computeHeightWithText:(NSString *)text font:(UIFont *)font width:(CGFloat)width
{
    UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    gettingSizeLabel.font = font;
    gettingSizeLabel.text = text;
    gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];

    return expectedSize.height;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives me back a larger height than my solution but the text still doesn't fit. I hope u can help me fix this :)

Comment: @JavedGeorge, and the label is inside a tableViewCell?

Comment: Yes it is. I tried to apply the width from the cell.textLabel.frame.size.width but this property returns 0, so I took [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width.

Comment: can you show us what's inside the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` and your customcell?